# gluon - iOS simulator - error downloading zips

Tags: ios-simulator, gluon

I'm trying to use the gluon iOS-simulator on my Mac (Catalina 10.15.4), using the maven-client-plugin, but I can't get past the man client:compile stage.    When I run that, I get the following error in the log file:

```
    [Wed May 06 10:47:01 EDT 2020][INFO] ==================== COMPILE TASK ====================
    [Wed May 06 10:47:01 EDT 2020][FINE] PB Command for check version: /Users/bobyetman/graalvm-svm-darwin-20.1.0-ea+26/bin/java -version
    [Wed May 06 10:47:01 EDT 2020][FINE] Start process check version...
    [Wed May 06 10:47:02 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB] openjdk version "11.0.5" 2019-10-15
    [Wed May 06 10:47:02 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB] OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.5+10-jvmci-19.3-b05-LTS)
    [Wed May 06 10:47:02 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB] OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM 20.1.0-dev (build 11.0.5+10-jvmci-19.3-b05-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
    [Wed May 06 10:47:02 EDT 2020][FINE] Result for check version: 0
    [Wed May 06 10:47:02 EDT 2020][INFO] We will now compile your code for x86_64-apple-ios. This may take some time.
    [Wed May 06 10:47:02 EDT 2020][FINE] Processing JavaStatic dependencies at /Users/bobyetman/.gluon/substrate/javaStaticSdk/15-ea+2/ios-x86_64/labs-staticjdk/lib/static
    [Wed May 06 10:47:02 EDT 2020][FINE] Processing JavaFXStatic dependencies at /Users/bobyetman/.gluon/substrate/javafxStaticSdk/15-ea+gvm16/ios-x86_64/sdk/lib
    [Wed May 06 10:47:02 EDT 2020][INFO] Downloading Java Static Libs...
    [Wed May 06 10:47:02 EDT 2020][FINE] Processing zip file: url = https://download2.gluonhq.com/substrate/staticjdk/labs-staticjdk-ios-x86_64-gvm-15-ea+2.zip, zip = /Users/bobyetman/.gluon/substrate/labs-staticjdk-ios-x86_64-gvm-15-ea+2.zip, subDir = javaStaticSdk, levels = [15-ea+2, ios-x86_64], md5 = javaStaticSdk-ios-x86_64.md5
    [Wed May 06 10:47:02 EDT 2020][SEVERE] Downloading failed: https://download2.gluonhq.com/substrate/staticjdk/labs-staticjdk-ios-x86_64-gvm-15-ea+2.zip
```

the pom is fairly plain:

> ```
> <plugin>
>   <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
>   <artifactId>client-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>   <version>0.1.21</version>
>        <configuration>
>            <target>ios-sim</target>
>            <mainClass>com.boby.ClosedKnightFX</mainClass>
>            <graalvmHome>/Users/bobyetman/graalvm-svm-darwin-20.1.0-ea+26</graalvmHome>
>    </configuration>
> ```

I've cut and pasted the URL to the zip file into my browser, and it says 'file not found'.   If I take out the target, and I can run the app on my Mac, it builds, links, and runs.

Suggestions?

Comment: iOS-simulator is not supported yet. See https://github.com/gluonhq/substrate/issues/252

Comment: Thanks for the info, didn't see that noted anywhere else.